# What's wrong with this Last.fm geo.getEvents API query?

Tags: rest, last.fm

I'm attempting to use the geo.getEvents method in Last.fm's Web services, which you can read about here:

http://www.last.fm/api/show/geo.getEvents

I'm attempting to use it like this:

http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.getevents&lat=40.7903&long=73.9597&api_key=0382f639e72b14c9265d41993d28a110&format=json

Those are the Latitude and Longitude coordinates for New York City. However, I get back a responses saying there are not events there. Even if I add a distance parameter, it says the same thing. Also if I round those coordinates to integers.

Is there something wrong with my queries, or is the service just messed up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New York is 73 deg. **WEST**, so you need to use a negative value for the longitude, and the URL should be:

http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.getevents&lat=40.7903&long=-73.9597&api_key=0382f639e72b14c9265d41993d28a110&format=json